# How to know DHCP options value on debian/ubuntu and other linux

Tags: dhcp, options

How to know all DHCP options and values (on the client side, Linux Ubuntu / Debian / ArchLinux ) provided by the server. I need to pass non-standard option to the client by the DHCP option
code example:

```
222-223 Unassigned 
224-254 Reserved (Private Use)
```

[All DHCP Options here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml)

The file /var/lib/dhcp.lease does not contiend my options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just edit the config file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and add `also request`

```
# custom dhcp option (72 = www-server)
also request www-server;
```

the value is avaible in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.lease`

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian based system with NetworkManager, the lease information is available in files like `/var/lib/NetworkManager/internal-$UUID-$IFACE.lease`.