# How to list DHCP options sent to a client from a DHCP server in Linux?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcpcd

How does one list the options that are sent to a client from a DHCP server? Using a utility run from bash?

Comment: Noting that the bash command-line is just a command-line, and doesn't affect the ability to list DHCP options.

Comment: You can monitor the DHCP traffic by installing and using `wireshark`. The actual DHCP "options" aren't saved anywhere - they're applied to the system, and reflected in the running system's configuration, until something changes them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tshark, the commandline version of wireshark, `tshark -tad -nn -VOdhcp -ixenbr0 -f 'ip and udp port 67'`

Answer (score 2):

The only way to see the options (unless the machine you are running this on **is** the client, then you can see the **effect** of the options) is to capture the traffic for the DHCP exchange.

So you use anything you like to monitor network traffic (`wireshark`, `tshark`, `tcpdump`, ...). There's also a dedicated tool called `dhcpdump`.

Note that you might not see what's going on with another client if your network setup doesn't allow to capture the traffic between the DHCP server and that client.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to at least one dhcp client machine, the received DHCP options can be found in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases`.

This question should probably be marked as a duplicate of [How to know DHCP options value on debian/ubuntu and other linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153332/how-to-know-dhcp-options-value-on-debian-ubuntu-and-other-linux)